# How to find a list of distributions (meta-distributions) based on Alpine?

Tags: alpine-linux

How can one find a list of distributions that have based their work on the effort of Alpine Linux?  Personally I'm very curious to find more robust desktop distro systems that bring the sanity of Alpine to a composition of packages that have sane defaults for general desktop use.

Comment: Hello, have you checked https://distrowatch.com/.

Comment: Yeah, but unless I'm missing something there's no option for Alpine under "Based on" within the advanced search page here: Notice: https://distrowatch.com/search.php#advanced

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there are two distro based on alpinelinux,

- https://adelielinux.org/ - for desktop
- https://postmarketos.org/ - for mobile

  - can work with alpine upstream.
- https://github.com/rancher/k3os - for Deploy K3S - immutable base system

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge in this. It's a shame there isn't such a function on distrowatch as I think it would be useful to have a running update of this. I was thinking I'd heard of another one as well, but haven't been able to recall it yet.

Comment: While Adelie uses Alpine's APK package manager: it is a systemd-free distro based on Gentoo, not Alpine.